# Code alignment plugin for notepad++ does not work properly

Tags: notepad++

With notepad++, I want to align column with several characters such as ':', '='. I found some plugin named 'code alignment' but this 'Align by' command does not align properly.

First image is an example code and second is an image after the 'Align by' command. I even tested for check boxes (Align from caret position, Use reguler expression) with all possible combinations but return same as second image. what shoud I do with this 'code alignment' plugin? I'd also appreciate it if you give some other plugin options.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. As far as issues you're having with the plugiin you're using now, contact the author of that plugin - no one here can help you with that, because we don't have access to the source.

Comment: @KenWhite My question is about formatting in notepad++ and there is lots of question of this kind. I did not understand perfectly that this question is off-topic. Is the question form what I lack?

Comment: The part that is off-topic is *I'd appreciate it if you give some other plugin options*, which is a request for an off-site resource, as I said before. We can't do anything about the plugin you're using now (as I also said), because we do not have access to its source code. Contact that plugins author.

Comment: @KenWhite Okay, thank you for your explanation. I understood that I need to find the author of this plugin to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown what result you expect. I think you have chosen a special style and font. With font 'Consolas' the plug-in works perfectly for me.

*Before:*

[image]

*After:*

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help much. I found out that font was the problem, but now I'm spending time on deleting those CR, LF (especially when I use '=' as a align parameter). I think the knowledge of reguler expression is what I need, is that right?